# After upgrading to 2.6.35-24 kernel, why does adb no longer list devices?

Tags: android

When I first installed Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit, I was able to see a physical Android device (connected via USB) in the Android Device Chooser (launched from Eclipse). But, after upgrading my kernel from `2.6.35-22-generic` to `2.6.35-24-generic`, no devices are listed any more, and I am unable to see any results when running `adb devices` like so:

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 

$
```

I have tried booting in the previous kernel version, but I get some `udev` error, so I was hoping I could get it working with the newer kernel version.

I figured SO was the best place for this question, as it seems more developer related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the cable! Perhaps coincidentally the cable sopped working after I did the kernel upgrade - hard to tell. I just bought a Nokia data cable, and that seemed to work fine with my HTC Legend.

Could also be worth noting that I had the seemingly common permissions problem (caused by not starting the adb server as root). So here's the solution:

```
# su

# ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions

# ./adb kill-server

# ./adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
HT03HNX00920    device

#
```

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same problem, my htc legend was not reconized by my ubuntu maverick 10.10. After reading the previous response, i took a nokia cable with micro-usb, and it works! so i examine carefully the htc cable, it's a china compatible cable (i've bought a second hand htc legend but never have a look for the quality of the cable...)

so just a cable problem.

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked on android on Ubuntu, but in my experience this has happened before on windows for me, when I had to install another driver (typically for a handset from another manufacturer). To fix it I usually reinstall the driver, that works usually.

If that doesnt work then see if that kernel is supported by google for android development. And good luck in this, it is not easy sometimes trying to resolve device driver issues.

Oh, before I forget, ensure that handset had "usb debugging" enabled, through handset UI.